# Selecting values ranked within the first quartile and label them as logical '1'

Tags: matlab

For example, a simplified version of the problem:

A =

```
 0      10     50
 20     30     20
 10     70     20
 40     20     10
```

I would like to get logical label for **every column** in which the value is ranked within the **first quartile (L)**, **second and third quartile (M)**, and the **fourth quartile (N)**. So that in the end I can get the output like this:

L =

```
 1      1      0
 0      0      0
 0      0      0
 0      0      1
```

M =

```
 0      0      0
 1      1      1
 1      0      1
 0      1      0
```

N =

```
 0      0      1
 0      0      0
 0      1      0
 1      0      0
```

In this 4x3 matrix example, each column has 4 values. First quartile (in rank) would mean the one with lowest value, 2nd and 3rd quartile would take second and third lowest value, 4th quartile would be the one with highest value. So, in another example, if a column has 40 values, then I want to label '1' for the lowest 10 values for the **first quartile** in the matrix, and so on and so forth.

Imagine I have 1000x1000 matrix.... The 'quantile' and 'percentile' functions cannot do this, as they do not rank the each cell value.  So, what I should do to achieve that?

Comment: I am not sure I understand your problem. What are these quarters? Could you explain the logic a bit more clearly?

Comment: I just further clarify the problem. Do you get me this time?

Comment: `L(3,1)` shouldn't be `1`?

Comment: @Katmal the 25% percentile of the first column is `5` so `L(3,1)` should be `0`

Comment: I though the percentiles are calculated with all the elements. Sorry for the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?:

```
pL = prctile(A,25,1);
pU = prctile(A,75,1);

L = bsxfun(@le, A, pL);
N = bsxfun(@ge, A, pU);
M = ones(size(A))-L-N;
```

**EDIT:**
If NaNs are present use this for `M` instead of the above:

`M = ~isnan(A)-L-N;`

Comment: I added 
pM = prctile(A,100,1);
M1 = bsxfun(@le, A, pM);
M  = M1 -L-N;

just in case A has NaN , and that will give me false positive using your 'M' command =)

Comment: Ok, feel free to edit my answer. In case of NaNs this would be a cleaner solution: `M = ~isnan(A)-L-N`.

Answer (score 2):

```
q = prctile(A, [25,75,100])

 5   15   15
30   50   35
40   70   50
```

We can use `bsxfun` to find all numbers below each of these points:

```
B = bsxfun(@le, A, permute(q, [3,2,1]);
```

And now you need to cumulatively multiply each matrix (along the third dimension) with the `~` of the previous matrix (i.e. `B(:,:,2) = B(:,:,2).*~B(:,:,1)`) which you could either do with a loop or you can vectorize it like so:

```
N = cat(3, ones(size(B,1), size(B,2)), ~B(:,:,1:end-1))
B.*N
```

returns:

```
ans(:,:,1) =

 1      1      0
 0      0      0
 0      0      0
 0      0      1

ans(:,:,2) =

 0      0      0
 1      1      1
 1      0      1
 0      1      0

ans(:,:,3) =

 0      0      1
 0      0      0
 0      1      0
 1      0      0
```

This method makes it very easy to extend should you want to find the indexes for different percentiles:

```
p = [25, 75, 100];
q = prctile(A, p);
B = bsxfun(@le, A, permute(q, [3,2,1]);
N = cat(3, ones(size(B,1), size(B,2)), ~B(:,:,1:end-1))
B.*N
```

So if you want it in quintiles for example just change `p` to `[20 40 60 80 100]`

Comment: Sorry Dan that I made you confused and misunderstood the problem.. it is really a bit difficult to describe. 

Actually, I am more interested in the ranking the numbers, than calculating them out. I would like to label those numbers with the lowest 25% with logical '1' in "L", 25-75% in "M" , the top 25% in "N". 

Then I will take L, M, N , further for other operations, which is not part of this problem.

Comment: @cheehanlim that's what this does. If you want the second and third quartiles together then either `|` them together or else just remove the second line from `q`

Comment: Thanks Dan, you provided the correct answer too. 

But I like Arpi's method as she/he can allow me to use the logical values in L,M,N in separate entity, and I can use those directly for the next move.

I must thank you for your patience with me, and thanks for showing me the way to get around the problem. I am still relatively new for Matlab.